# ${}$ Regarding Michelson-Morley Experiment

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, aether

Why the Michelson-Morley experiment was rotated by 90 degree.
$$Δt = (2/c)(l1-l2) + (2v²/c³)(l1-{l2/2})$$
The above expression is the time difference before the rotation. Then why there is the need of rotation??
This is what I think. Please rectify my answer for its × or explain my answer elaborately for its ✓.

If we assume that ether is not present, then the velocity of ether that is v will be zero. But that does not confirm that the time difference is 0 because of the first term in the above equation. So at any cost we have to make the arm length equal which is is not possible very precisely and accurately. one of the finest way as thought by Michelson was to rotate the stem by 90 degrees so that L1 becomes L2 and L2 becomes L1. So since they rotated the system they have to look for a new output result in telescope unlike the previous case of before rotation where they have to only check if the fringes are coming or not. This new output in telescope which they have to look was a fringe shift. This fringe shift arrived because the rotation changed the time difference hence the path difference followed by the shift in fringe.
Now the difference in time before rotation and after rotation they got was
Δt' = (v²/c³)(L1+L2)
This is what they wanted-the direct dependence of of the time difference on the velocity of Ether medium

Comment: Are you asking why one of interferometer arm's was rotated by $90^{\circ}$ to the other arm or something different ?

Comment: Whole system is rotated

Comment: Whole system is rotated, because if ether exists, interference pattern should shift, when different arm is aligned with ether, instead of previous arm.

Comment: Not opposing ur point kindly answer the question as the format of question. Kindly confirm first if my logic is ok or not . If ok explain it more elaborately if not ok then rectify

Comment: If you replace the term "telescope" with "interferometer", then your description is pretty much correct, if I understand you correctly. If the light speed in the two directions would not be identical, then rotating the equipment would change the time difference between the two arms, which would show up as a shift in the fringes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The starting point is different, the ether exists and its effect would be to affect the velocity due to a counteracting force (what they actually wanted to prove).

Changing the direction of the arms implies a different effect on the light path and so on the shift of the fringes. But the shift has to be of a given quantity, they instead obtained a very small shift that could not be related to the ether.

> The Experiments on the relative motion of the earth and ether have been completed and the result decidedly negative. The expected deviation of the interference fringes from the zero should have been 0.40 of a fringe – the maximum displacement was 0.02 and the average much less than 0.01 – and then not in the right place. As displacement is proportional to squares of the relative velocities it follows that if the ether does slip past the relative velocity is less than one sixth of the earth’s velocity.

— Albert Abraham Michelson, 1887